# Android Studio Firebase Installation: ERROR: File google-services.json is missing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have already following the instructions to add firebase to the android studio's project, I have already download google-services.json and move it into the root folder project, but still get error notifications "File google-services.json is missing".

[image]

Comment: Your google-services.json file in the wrong directory. Just cut and paste inside app folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to add your google-services.json inside your app folder and not your gradle folder.

From your ss that u provided it is been added to the gradle folder.

Drag nd Drop the file into your app folder -> Clean project -> Rebuild project.

Comment: Most welcome! Be aware during development haha...nd pls do upvote nd accept the ans so that others may know the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

Select project from the dropdown on topleft(by default it is Android)

Then paste your json file inside app folder.

[image: sample]